# Is it possible to run APPCMD from Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-7, appcmd

In our transitory migration situation, I have the need to run APPCMD from a Windows Server 2003 machine, but of course targeting an IIS7 instance on a remote Windows Server 2008.

Is it possible?

(I am NOT trying to run IIS7 on Windows Server 2003)

Nick

Answer (score 1):

appcmd doesn't have a way to remotely control any machine (even between 2 W2k8 machines) so the answer to your question is no.

Just out of curiosity I tried copying appcmd.exe from a W2k8 box to a W2k3 box, and I get an error that the executable "is not a valid Win32 application".

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with PsExec on the Windows Server 2003 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running this command on the prompt:

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs
```